# how can i use Any Cpu Mode to run my Application when using Nokia imaging Sdk in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I am using Nokia Imaging Sdk for imaging effects in my Application like Blur,Brightness and many more.I have completed my application now i have to upload it to Windows Phone Store but i'm unable to run my application in AnyCpu Mode.Can anyone plzz Suggest..

Comment: Why do you want to use AnyCpu mode?

Comment: i want to publish my app on Windows Phone Store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot build an app referencing Nokia Imaging SDK in for AnyCPU, because it itself is not built for AnyCPU, it consists of separate binaries for ARM and X86.

Comment: So how can i publish my app using Nokia imaging effcts on windows store??  To publish an app we should have AnyCpu mode xap file.

Comment: you publish the ARM build, that is ok